# Existing Function to find the number of missing and complete cases

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

**Statement of Problem**

Is there a function in an existing package which will give the number of missing elements (i.e. `NA`'s) and number of complete elements for each column of a data frame relatively easily?

I am able to solve this problem with the approach mentioned below, however I was wondering whether there is a package which will do this for me (mainly to have the convenience of not repeating this code every time I perform data analysis).

**Current Solution 1**

I am able to find out this information using the following functions I have written

```
# Find number of missing elements
missing.total = function(df){
  sum(is.na(df))
}

# Find number of complete elements
complete.total = function(df){
  sum(!is.na(df))
}

# Find number of complete and missing elements for each variable in a data frame
var.complete.info = function(df){
  result = cbind( apply(df, 2, complete.total),
                  apply(df, 2, missing.total) )

  colnames(result) = c("Complete", "Missing")

  return(result)
}
```

We can apply this function on the following example:

```
set.seed(1)

n.col = 5
n.row = 100
sample.set = c(0:9, NA)

# Create sample data frame with missing and complete
sample.df = data.frame(replicate(n.col,sample(sample.set,n.row,rep=TRUE)))

> var.complete.info(sample.df)
   Complete Missing
X1       95       5
X2       92       8
X3       89      11
X4       88      12
X5       86      14
```

**Current Solution 2**

Another option is to use the `skim()` function in the `skimr` library but this gives too much information:

```
library(skimr)

# Using sample.df as defined above in solution 1

# Gives more information than necessary
> skim(sample.df)
Skim summary statistics
 n obs: 100 
 n variables: 5 

── Variable type:integer ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 variable missing complete   n mean   sd p0  p25 p50 p75 p100     hist
       X1       5       95 100 4.96 2.79  0 3      5   7    9 ▅▃▃▅▃▂▅▇
       X2       8       92 100 4.75 2.72  0 2.75   5   7    9 ▆▃▅▅▃▆▃▇
       X3      11       89 100 3.57 2.51  0 1      3   5    9 ▇▃▃▃▃▂▂▂
       X4      12       88 100 4.3  2.78  0 2      4   7    9 ▇▃▅▅▅▂▃▆
       X5      14       86 100 4.26 2.9   0 1.25   4   7    9 ▇▂▂▅▅▂▃▅
```

**Ideal solution**

I'm looking for an existing package to do the work for me so I'm hoping to find a package which will allow me to code as follows:

```
library(Package_I_am_not_aware_of)

existing.function(data_frame)
```

Comment: You may want to look into the `VIM` packages which has nice missing-handling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `VIM::aggr()` would suit you.

```
library(VIM)
summary(aggr(d, plot=FALSE))
# Missings per variable: 
#   Variable Count
# X1     7
# X2     9
# X3    10
# X4    14
# 
# Missings in combinations of variables: 
#   Combinations Count   Percent
# 0:0:0:0     5 16.666667
# 0:0:0:1     3 10.000000
# 0:0:1:0     3 10.000000
# 0:0:1:1     3 10.000000
# 0:1:0:0     4 13.333333
# 0:1:0:1     3 10.000000
# 0:1:1:0     1  3.333333
# 0:1:1:1     1  3.333333
# 1:0:0:0     2  6.666667
# 1:0:0:1     3 10.000000
# 1:0:1:0     1  3.333333
# 1:0:1:1     1  3.333333
```

To get just the top part you can extract the values saved in a `data.frame`.

```
out <- summary(aggr(d, plot=FALSE))
out$missings
#    Variable Count
# X1       X1     7
# X2       X2     9
# X3       X3    10
# X4       X4    14
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, NA, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, NA, NA, 15L, NA, 17L, NA, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, NA, 29L, 30L), X2 = c(31L, 32L, 33L, NA, 
NA, 36L, NA, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, NA, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, NA, NA, NA, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, NA, 58L, 59L, NA), 
    X3 = c(61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, NA, 68L, 69L, 70L, NA, 
    72L, NA, NA, NA, 76L, NA, 78L, NA, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L), X4 = c(NA, NA, 93L, 94L, 95L, 
    96L, NA, NA, NA, 100L, NA, NA, 103L, NA, 105L, NA, 107L, 
    108L, 109L, NA, NA, NA, 113L, 114L, NA, NA, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
    120L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Is it possible to just isolate the top part (i.e. just the "Missings per variable:" section without the "Missings in combinations of variables:" section)?

Answer (score 1):

With `skimr` we can actually change the default summary functions using `skim_with`:

```
library(skimr)

funs <- get_skimmers()$numeric
skim_with(integer = list(Complete = funs$complete, Missing = funs$missing), append = FALSE)
skim(sample.df)
```

**Output:**

```
Skim summary statistics
 n obs: 100 
 n variables: 5 

-- Variable type:integer ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 variable Complete Missing
       X1       95       5
       X2       92       8
       X3       89      11
       X4       88      12
       X5       86      14
```